# can messages be passed between states

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I've set up some directional movements for my main character;
Right, left, up, down, up left, up right, down left, down right.

This works ok and I also want to use this information to trigger the movement of  other objects within their own states. However, if I send a message 'ultrue' (upper left key has been pressed), then inside other objects' states that message is not recognised.

Is this even possible or should I use a property? If so, how?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 2):

States define what logic is currently active. Inactive logic will not do anything. This means when your message sensor is not connected to a controller of an active state it will not sense anything.

If you really need you either:

- connect the message sensor to a controller at each state
- add another state that is always active (yes, you can activate multiple states at the same time) and move the message processing to that state